# WordPress Block Variation for Gallery Columns

Tags: block-editor, gallery

I had this code to extend the column count to 10 for a specific need.

```js
wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation('core/gallery', {
  name: 'prefix-gallery',
  title: 'Custom Gallery',
  attributes: {
    columns: 10,
  },
  isDefault: true,
});
```

But that doesn't seem to work any longer. I see the updated Block Gallery attributes has this:

```js
attributes: {
  {
    columns: {
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 1,
      "maximum": 10,
    },
  },
}
```

So I tried:

```js
wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation('core/gallery', {
  name: 'prefix-gallery',
  title: 'Custom Gallery',
  attributes: {
    columns: {
      minimum: 1,
      maximum: 10,
    },
  },
  isDefault: true,
});
```

That doesn't seem to work to extend the column count to 10.

Anyone now how to adjust the block variation to 10 instead of the default 8?

Comment: have you tried matching your override with the new setup? Yours is missing parameters the new setup has such as the type. Even then, this will mean galleries still have 8 columns and the user would have to manually increase it to 10 on the slider

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes I have tried that as well. Thank you for your reply though!

Comment: I don't know much about block coding (wish I did), but just based off coding...you didn't put quotes around `minimum` or `maximum` or `columns` (or anything else that needed it) and you didn't add `type` to the columns array.